# Copy value from HTML controls to ASP.NET user control

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm new to this world. Let me explain you by photos.[image]

Here is the first photo, I have a user control called "Adress.ascx" and on this page there are 2 different types of controls.

1. Asp.net controls (red)
2. Html controls (green)

This user control, I have implemented on another page called **Index.aspx**

[image]

What I want to do is, whenever I click on the button "Copy button", whatever is in the html controls copy to User control.

On Html controls, I'm using Google Maps API to search addresses.

Even, if I don't implement my user control to another page, I'm not able to copy html controls value to asp.net user controls.

For example, I have one asp:TextBox called **tbStreet** on user control and one Html textbox whose ID is **id=street_name**. I want to copy **street_name**'s value to **tbStreet**.

Asp.net control code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbStreet" runat="server" MaxLength="50" 
 CssClass="inputfield M"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Html control code

```
<input class="field" id="street_name" name="streetName"
            disabled="true"></input></td>
```

Button code

```
protected void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string street = Request.Form["street_name"];

    }
```

But I don't get any value in variable **street**

Comment: Please refer to this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't understand the question. The pictures confuse me more than anything.

Comment: Provide [mcve] code to explain your issue - without code it's hard to find solution from this question.

Comment: Please find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012162/get-html-value-on-web-user-control-without-runat-server/47030751#47030751) I have resolved it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML input like this:

```
<input class="field" id="street_name" name="streetName" />
```

You should set the `name` attribute value as `Request.Form` argument instead of `id`:

```
protected void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string street = Request.Form["streetName"].ToString();
}
```

Note that `disabled` attribute prevents value to be submitted in postback, I recommend to remove that attribute and replace it with `readonly` if you just want to disallow users editing its value:

```
<input class="field" id="street_name" name="streetName" readonly="readonly" />
```

If the text box belongs to a usercontrol, you can create a property to get the text value from it, assumed the input element has `runat="server"` attribute:

```
public string StreetName
{
    get { return street_name.Text; }
}
```

Then you can access usercontrol object properties with this:

```
UserControl control = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("UserControlId");
string street = control.StreetName;
```

Comment: I have tried to make a property but no luck. I thinks its a User control and maybe something extra we need to do. If I just create a normal aspx page there I can retrieve the values but from User control I have no idea what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx

The element is referenced by name rather than ID, so:

```
string street = Request.Form["streetName"];
```

Comment: thank you very much, I have tried even with ID but not luck.

Comment: Yes your code shows that you're using ID, have you tried with Name?

Comment: yes I have tried with Name. Maybe I have to cast like (Adres)Request.Form["streetName"];? because it is on a UserControl page?