# Get html value on Web User Control without runat="server"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm new to this world.

[image]

As you can see in the picture. This is my **Default.aspx** page where I have implemented a Web User Control(uc) called "**adress.ascx**".

My uc control is divided in 2 categories, first is **Asp.net** controls category and second is **Html** Controls category.

What is the scenario: I want to **copy** the value from Html Textbox to Asp:TextBox.

I have 2 options, either I can do with **asp:Button** or with html button(**without runat="server"**)

Here is my code

```
<h1>ASP.NET Controls</h1>
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Street"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbStreet" Text=""></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnAsp" Text="Button ASP" runat="server" 
OnClick="btnAsp_Click" 
/>

<h2>-------------------------------</h2>

<h1>Html Controls</h1>
Street
<input type="text" name="Street" id="street"><br />
<br />
<button type="button" id="btnStreet">Button HTML!</button>
```

And here is my code "code behind" in c#

```
protected void btnAsp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = Request.Form["street"];
}
```

When I run this code, the value I get is **null**
[image]

Comment: did you try to put `name="street"` on you `asp:TextBox`?

Comment: I take it you do have a `form` control on the page?

Comment: @ElmerDantas yes I have tried both name and id both but no luck.

Comment: @Fred Yes I have a form on the control

Comment: add `type="submit"` to the `asp:button` and read the values in the method the action of the form is set to.

Comment: Or add `type="button"` and `<input type="text" name="Street" id="street" runat="server">`  then in the code behind on `btnAsp_Click` you can use `string value = street.Text`

Comment: @Fred I don't want to add runat="server" because I'm using a script of Google Maps API and If add runat="server" then it does not work. And type="submit" on asp:button it does not show in the intellisense

Comment: better use Javascript_doPostBack() on onclick event of html button @user

Comment: @user2983359 Is it not working because it's changing the ID of the control? If that's the case, there is a way around that.

Comment: If you just want to transfer the data from the HTML input to the ASP Textbox, can you use jQuery?

Comment: @AdrianWragg no it is not changing the ID of the control. In fact it is just returning null value

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" in title, instead post an answer or accept the answer that solved the problem for you see [tour]

Comment: @user2983359 Have you used the browser tools in order to confirm the form fields being passed back, and examined `Request.Form` itself? The solutions so far presented are over-complex, it could be that you're just hitting a case-sensitivity issue.

However, at the same time it may be worth examining what you're trying to achieve here; there could be a better way within WebForms itself (or, if you're not tied to WebForms, MVC).

Answer (score 0):

```
 I hope you will find this helpful .

**Aspx Page**
<input type='button' id='btnAsp1' value='Shop Now' class='form-control' 
value='Button:1' onclick='javascript:__doPostBack("btnAsp1");' 
style='background-color:#3465aa; color:white' >

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
    if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.form1;
    }
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
            theForm.submit();
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>

 **Code Behind**
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && 
    Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "btnAsp1")
    {
        btnAsp1_Click(null, null);
    }
}

private void btnAsp1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("You Clicked on " + 
    Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Dhawal but I'm looking for something very simple. I'm really surprised that MS did not think about that.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine @user

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
Code for **Defualt.aspx** page.

```
    <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="Add" TagPrefix="uc1" 
    %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

             <uc1:Add runat="server" ID="ucAdres" WidthFirstCollumn="175px" />


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the code for WebUserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>



<form  method="post" runat="server"
>
<h1>ASP.NET Controls</h1>
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Street" ID="lable"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbStreet" Text="Text Asp.net text box"></asp:TextBox><br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnAsp" runat="server" Text="Button Asp.net" OnClick="btnAsp_Click"/><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnHtml" value="Html Button" />

<h2>-------------------------------</h2>

    <h1>Html Controls</h1>
    Street

    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" value="Text coming from HTML5"">
    <br />
    <br />

    <button type="button" id="btnStreet">Button HTML!</button>

    </form>
```

And here is the code of WebUserControl.ascx.cs

```
protected void btnAsp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = Page.Request.Form["street"].ToString();
        if (value != null)
        {
            tbStreet.Text = value;
        } else
        {
            tbStreet.Text = "Nooooooooo";
        }
    }
```

I explain again, that you have a WebUserControl where you have 2 types of Controls(Asp.net and html). What you want to do is to copy from HTML to asp.net without runat="server".
I often has problem of **Form** so finally I found that I have 2 **Forms**, 1 on WebUserControl and 1 on Default.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows a breakpoint on the following line:

```
string value = Request.Form["street"];
```

with value being `null`. However, from [Using Breakpoints on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> When you run this code in the debugger, execution stops whenever the breakpoint is hit, **before the code on that line is executed**

If you go to the next line, the line will run and populate `value`. To copy this into the ASP.net control, the following should be sufficient:

```
protected void btnAsp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbStreet.Text = Request.Form["street"];
}
```

I would caution that what you are trying to do probably has a better solution, so even if this solves your immediate problem you may find that other issues crop up further down the line.